# If I add a constructor to an extension of the AuthorizeAttribute will the constructor be called on every request that has the attribute attached?

Tags: c#, security, authorize, system.web

I have written a custom extension of the the `System.Web.Mvc AuthorizeAttribute`.
 The Microsoft Reference here : [SystemWebMvcAuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_AuthorizeAttribute__ctor).

This extension overrides the `AuthorizeCore` function from `AuthorizeAttribute`, and the intended use is that this custom attribute will retain the existing functionality of `AuthorizeAttribute`, but also perform an additional check on the user's session if a `config` setting is set to true.

We are worried about performance since this custom attribute will be attached to every API request, replacing the currently used `Authorize` attribute. Currently, in the `AuthorizeCore` function, we are reading the `config` setting on every single request, and are wondering if there is a better way of doing things.

So, if I create a constructor for my custom attribute, read the `config` there, and then store it in a `static` variable, does anyone know if this constructor will be called on every single request made which has this custom attribute attached, or just once, and then every call to `AuthorizeCore` (invoked when a request is made) can refer to the `static` variable storing the value that has already been read from the `config`?

```
public class AuthorizeSessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    bool _manageSession = false;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Since we are overriding the AuthorizeCore from AuthorizeAttribute, make sure to call the base method first to check that this request 'isAuthorized' before proceeding.
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if (isAuthorized)
        { 
            // Any way to improve this?
            bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManageSession"], out _manageSession);

            if (_manageSession)
            {
                // custom logic goes here
            }
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need constructor. You just need to add a static class bool? (Nullable bool) variable. Then in your method, only read data from config if your variable is null. In next execution, since its not null, it doesnt read config.

public class AuthorizeSessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private static bool? _manageSession;

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // Since we are overriding the AuthorizeCore from AuthorizeAttribute, make sure to call the base method first to check that this request 'isAuthorized' before proceeding.
    bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

    if (isAuthorized)
    { 
        if (!_manageSession.HasValue && bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManageSession"], out bool parsedSetting))
        {
            _manageSession = parsedSetting;
        }

        if (_manageSession)
        {
            // custom logic goes here
        }
    }
    return isAuthorized;
}
```

}

Comment: This might be the best suggestion. I've just tried adding a constructor to be custom attribute and yes, to answer my own question this constructor is called on every API request that  has my custom attribute attached.

Your suggestion would replace a call to Configuration.AppSettings and bool.TryParse on every request to simply a null check on every request. Sounds less expensive to me so I'll go with it.